How to hide Icon chrome when use selenium C#
I'm working with Selenium and have to use it show up but not in headless mode.(Already setting position for browser, Because there is an capcha image on the Website I have to capture so cannot use headless mode)
But also I need to hide the icon of chrome when it show up on the taskbar
Is there any solution ?
The answer that I have looked on stackoverflow is hard to understand


Which answer is hard to understand? How will you understand any other answer? It's not Selenium that you're trying to hide. You're trying to tell Windows to not display an active application. That's not easy

What are you trying to do anyway? There may be better solutions. In a desktop app you could use WebView2 to embed a browser so you don't have to start another one. You can control that browser view up to a point, or you can use Playwright in combination with WebView. Playwright is easier that Selenium anyway, removing the need for waiting.

Due to the page that I navigate to dectect that webview is not an trusted browser so it not allow me to keep doing it

everything working find with headless mode, except the capcha img that i cannot get it directly by findElement. It will call the link to generate the capcha again, so I try to screen shot but it not working in headless
